# How can we read the name from the following format

Tags: php

When I use preg_match_all("#BT(.*)ET#ismU", ,)   for extracting name from the below martix.I can't read the namePETER NIBIN CHERUPARAMBIL

```
Tj ET q 2950 3380 2142 221 re W n BT 1 0 0 -1 2950 3545 Tm 0 0 0 sc /a 143 Tf (PETER NIBIN) Tj ET Q BT 1 0 0 -1 975 3525 Tm 0 0 0 sc /a 143 Tf (555555555) Tj 8000 0 Td 0 0.502 0.251 sc (Entered to Country) Tj -1785 0 Td 0 0 0 sc (03-04-2014) Tj -4240 -379 Td (ALVIN JOY JOY) Tj -1975 20 Td (666666) Tj 8000 0 Td 0 0.502 0.251 sc (Entered to Country) Tj -1785 0 Td 0 0 0 sc (03-04-2014) Tj -4240 -379 Td (TONY KAIPPALLY DANIEL) .
```

How can I Read the name PETER NIBIN CHERUPARAMBIL from the above matrix?

Comment: I dont see `CHERUPARAMBIL` on the text dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with following regex:

```
/\(([A-Z ]+)\)/
```

#### The code..

```
<?php
$str='Tj ET q 2950 3380 2142 221 re W n BT 1 0 0 -1 2950 3545 Tm 0 0 0 sc /a 143 Tf (PETER NIBIN) Tj ET Q BT 1 0 0 -1 975 3525 Tm 0 0 0 sc /a 143 Tf (555555555) Tj 8000 0 Td 0 0.502 0.251 sc (Entered to Country) Tj -1785 0 Td 0 0 0 sc (03-04-2014) Tj -4240 -379 Td (ALVIN JOY JOY) Tj -1975 20 Td (666666) Tj 8000 0 Td 0 0.502 0.251 sc (Entered to Country) Tj -1785 0 Td 0 0 0 sc (03-04-2014) Tj -4240 -379 Td (TONY KAIPPALLY DANIEL) .';
preg_match_all('/\(([A-Z ]+)\)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

It will match uppercase text (letters with whitespaces) between brackets, so it will match:

- `PETER NIBIN`
- `ALVIN JOY JOY`
- `TONY KAIPPALLY DANIEL`

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/133785)